# generating 12 random color for each month

Tags: php, fusioncharts

i have this setting to setup pallet color for fusionchart bar graph

```
"paletteColors": "#594a2d,#660057,#6e8cff,#3d0c4e,#9ce6ae,#009e78,#001f8f,#ff7852,#ebff26,#0073e6,#f05eff,#00decc",
```

im trying to generate 12 random color code for each month of the year to put in the setting...

or use the 12 colors code from above but make it random for each loop ?

```
 #594a2d,#660057,#6e8cff,#3d0c4e,#9ce6ae,#009e78,#001f8f,#ff7852,#ebff26,#0073e6,#f05eff,#00decc
```

what i tried so far..this is working for random color..but what if i want to use the predefined color ?

```
<?php $rand = dechex(rand(0x000000, 0xFFFFFF));?>

"paletteColors": "<?php echo('#' . $rand);

for ($d=0;$d<12;$d++)
{
echo(',#' . $rand);
}

 ?>",
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [`shuffle`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) function which move elements of an array to random positions. Thus you can shuffle an array with predefined colors and use the first twelve elements of it:

```
$colors = explode(',', '#594a2d,#660057,#6e8cff,#3d0c4e,#9ce6ae,#009e78,#001f8f,#ff7852,#ebff26,#0073e6,#f05eff,#00decc');

shuffle($colors);
for ($i = 0; $i < 12; $i++) {
    echo($colors[$i]);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the function shuffle()

```
$arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];
shuffle($arr);
print_r($arr);
```

result is

```
Array ( [0] => 8 [1] => 2 [2] => 6 [3] => 10 [4] => 1 [5] => 9 [6] => 3 [7] => 5 [8] => 4 [9] => 12 [10] => 7 [11] => 11 )
```